# Import multiple CSV fields into one MySQL field

Tags: mysql, import

I'm trying to import our CSV data log into our MySQL.

The first two fields of the CSV are Date and Time, and I would like to combine that into one date time (which can be searched) onto MySQL.

**CSV:**

```
Date,Time,ALARM_01,PT001,TEMP_AMB
14/08/2014,14:23:21,0,130.00,20
14/08/2014,14:23:25,101,128.09,20.1
```

**MySQL Table:**

```
----------------------------------------------
|DateTime           |ALARM_01|PT001 |TEMP_AMB|
----------------------------------------------
|2014-08-14 14:23:21|0       |130.00|20      |
|2014-08-14 14:23:25|101     |128.09|20.1    |
----------------------------------------------
```

Could you please let me know how this is possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `LOAD DATA` sentence loads the CSV file, ignoring the first line and inserting into the desired fields, but changing the format of the Date and Time columns into a proper `datetime` type:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/alarms.csv' 
       INTO TABLE alarms 
       COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' 
       IGNORE 1 LINES 
       (@Date, @Time, ALARM_01, PT001, TEMP_AMB) 
       SET DateTime = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@Date, ' ', @Time), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM alarms;
+----+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+
| id | DateTime            | ALARM_01 | PT001  | TEMP_AMB |
+----+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+
|  1 | 2014-08-14 14:23:21 |        0 | 130.00 |    20.00 |
|  2 | 2014-08-14 14:23:25 |      101 | 128.09 |    20.10 |
+----+---------------------+----------+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your fields and datatypes may vary slightly, with no effect on the import query.

Comment: Cheers dude, works great :D

Comment: One more bit of help, if you wouldn't mind - Is it possible to match columns somehow, if the db and the CSV headers didn't match up, and further more, if the CSV has more columns than I would require in the db.

Cheers!

Comment: @adalal Just use variables and `SET` the columns you want; do not use the unrequired ones. Look at how I did it with @Date and @Time above.